# Why opaque views are more effective on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I tried to find other reasons why opaque views are better than transparent. However, the only sensible reason I came up with is that the view behind the opaque one doesn't need to draw its content at that place.

Is this a wrong assumption and are there other good reasons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right assumption. Directly from Apple documentation:

> `opaque`
>
> A Boolean value that determines
>   whether the receiver is opaque.
>
> `@property(nonatomic, getter=isOpaque) BOOL opaque`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This property provides a hint to the drawing system
>   as to how it should treat the view. If
>   set to `YES`, the drawing system treats
>   the view as fully opaque, which allows
>   the drawing system to optimize some
>   drawing operations and improve
>   performance. If set to `NO`, the drawing
>   system composites the view normally
>   with other content. The default value
>   of this property is `YES`.
>
> An opaque view is expected to fill its
>   bounds with entirely opaque
>   content—that is, the content should
>   have an alpha value of `1.0`. If the
>   view is opaque and either does not
>   fill its bounds or contains wholly or
>   partially transparent content, the
>   results are unpredictable. You should
>   always set the value of this property
>   to `NO` if the view is fully or
>   partially transparent.

Comment: While the documentation tells you that setting the opaque property to YES may improve performance, it doesn't exactly tell you the technical reason why this is true. The fact is that the iPhone's graphics processor isn't terribly great at compositing operations, as it doesn't natively handle alpha components in images. That is why PNGs are "optimised" before being put on the device. The alpha component is premultiplied with the other components so that the graphics processor can properly deal with it. More compositing means more work for the processor and as a result, worse performance.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from being able to avoid drawing the background view, there are a few other reasons it's faster, related to compositing:

1) There's no need to blend the foreground and background views, which saves some math done on every pixel

2) If the view moves, its pixels can simply be blitted to their new locations without any redrawing at all. This is a *huge* deal for scrolling performance, even on desktop computers, let alone mobile devices.